# It seems a failure to track back error mechanism from DEM to circuit faults

Tags: stim

This question is related to [Within Stim, how to trace back DEM error instructions to Stim circuit faults](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26623/within-stim-how-to-trace-back-dem-error-instructions-to-stim-circuit-faults).

I created a circuit of a distance-3 square surface code as you can see in the picture.
[image: Distance-3 square surface code]

The DEM file contains one error mechanism '''error(0.000266738) D6 D7 D12 D13'''. I want to know which circuit faults in the original circuit contributed to this error mechanism.

So I use the following code:

```
dem_errors_to_explain = stim.DetectorErrorModel("""
    error(0.000266738) D6 D7 D12 D13
""")

circuit_errors = circuit.explain_detector_error_model_errors(
    dem_filter=dem_errors_to_explain,
    reduce_to_one_representative_error=True
)

print(circuit_errors[0])
```

The result is as followings:

```
ExplainedError {
dem_error_terms: D6[coords 0,1,1] D7[coords 2,1,1] D12[coords 1,0,1] D13[coords 3,0,1]
CircuitErrorLocation {
    flipped_pauli_product: X2[coords 2,0]*X1[coords 1,0]
    Circuit location stack trace:
        (after 10 TICKs)
        at instruction #50 (a REPEAT 10 block) in the circuit
        after 0 completed iterations
        at instruction #13 (DEPOLARIZE2) in the REPEAT block
        at targets #1 to #2 of the instruction
        resolving to DEPOLARIZE2(0.001) 2[coords 2,0] 1[coords 1,0]
}
```

We could find that Stim tells us the error mechanism contributing to syndrome '''D6 D7 D12 D13''' is the two-qubit error '''XX''' on qubit 1 and 2 after the depolarization channel.
However, this seems not correct because two X errors on qubit 1 and 2 will only lead to defects D12 and D13.

So where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note all four detectors in the screenshot mention `rec[18]` or `rec[19]`, which are flipped by the annotated error. Probably what happened is you accidentally declared the same detectors twice, but were tricked by the diagram code drawing the detector on the qubit that most closely matched the detector's coordinate data, making it appear like it was checking the measurement on that qubit.

As a way to catch this kind of error, I recommend glancing at the `circuit.diagram("detslice-with-ops-svg")` image (needs v1.11+). It should immediately jump out that part of the circuit isn't covered.

Alternatively, in [my half-janky released code from papers](https://github.com/Strilanc/midout/blob/main/src/midout/gen/_viz_circuit_html.py) I have a utility class that makes diagrams annotating each measurement with the detectors that depend on it. This is also an easy way to catch the issue, because the measurements with accidental extra detector dependents (or no dependents!) stand out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I have figured it out.

Comment: As for circuit.diagram("detslice-with-ops-svg"), I don't understand what's the meaning of the graph at each time slice

Comment: @Jerry It's showing where each detector is detecting errors at that time.